# Edit GUI with WindowBuilder

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I have to work on a project, where GUI is already given. I need to edit it, is there any way to open the Design view with WindowBuilder of this GUI?

I'm working on Eclipse and use WindowBuilder as plugin.

Plugin doesn't recognize it and can't parse automatically.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we cannot edit an existing GUI made without using websitebuilder plugin as it is not saved with the meta associated with files made using websitebuilder.

You can however create a new file with new GUI and copy code to previous file.